# Hangfire doesn't create tables in IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have installed Hangfire in my ASP.Core 2.2 project using this guide https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html .

When I delete my `MyProject_dev`MSSQL db and run `Update-Database` only my custom tables are created. After I run the project, the Hangfire tables are added.

In `appsettings.production.json` I have configured the db to be `MyProject_prod` and I click on *Folder* publish with checked *Entity Framework Migrations* so the build process can create a *.sql* file in the `EFSQLScripts` folder with the SQL I need to apply to the `MyProject_prod` database.

The problem is that the .sql file contains only my custom tables. When I run the IIS site the Hangfire tables aren't created in `MyProject_prod` db, in comparison to when I run the project with *F5* locally, where they are created in `MyProject_dev` if they do not exists. Looking at the logs I see that the connection to the `MyProject_prod` db is made, the error is:

```
[ERR] Execution BackgroundServerProcess is still in the Failed state for 00:20:45.1406056 due to an exception, will be retried no more than in 00:00:15
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'HangFire.Server'.
```

I could export the tables from my `MyProject_dev` db and import them in the `MyProject_prod` db, but I don't think this would be the right approach. Why aren't the tables created when the app is run under IIS?

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073911/hangfire-does-not-process-recurring-jobs-unless-dashboard-is-open

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the database manually in production, without adding any tables. In your config, point it at the newly created db. This may be an issue with hangfire bot having the permissions to build create the database.